# Which hybrid classes give alternative ways to calculate AC?

Tags: dnd-4e, class, armor-class

In D&D 4e some hybrid classes provide alternative ways to calculate AC.

I know about Hybrid Runepriests (Serene Blade) using Wisdom.
What other class-ability combinations are there?

Comment: Just re question type: There is no problem with questions that ask for the list of things that do X in set Y. There is a different type of question (poorly named 'list-questions') which are problematic because they ask such that there is no end of answers and no real way of sorting them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the available hybrid options for increasing your AC outside of armor proficiency.

### Strength

- **Hybrid Seeker:** You can select your basic Seeker's Bond type as Spiritbond and spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** for True Seeker's Bond to use Str as your AC bonus stat when not wearing heavy armor.
- **Hybrid Sorcerer:** You can select your basic Sorcerous Power damage bonus stat as Strength to use Str as your AC bonus stat when not wearing heavy armor.

### Constitution

- **Hybrid Druid:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Primal Aspect; select Primal Guardian to use Con as your AC bonus stat when not wearing heavy armor.
- **Hybrid Warden:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Warden's Armored Might; in addition to the armor proficiencies, you can select Earthstrength or Stormheart as your Guardian Might to use Con as your AC bonus stat when not wearing heavy armor.

### Wisdom

- **Hybrid Runepriest:** You can select your basic Runic Artistry type as Serene Blade to use Wis as your AC bonus stat when not wearing heavy armor.
- **Hybrid Warden:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Warden's Armored Might; in addition to the armor proficiencies, you can select Lifespirit or Wildblood as your Guardian Might to use Wis as your AC bonus stat when not wearing heavy armor.

### Other

- **Hybrid Avenger:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Armor of Faith, a +3 untyped bonus to AC when not wearing heavy armor or using a shield.
- **Hybrid Barbarian:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Barbarian Armored Agility, which includes both armor proficiencies and a +1 untyped bonus per tier to AC and Reflex when not wearing heavy armor.
- **Hybrid Monk:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Unarmored Defense, a +2 untyped bonus to AC when wearing cloth armor or no armor and not holding a shield.
- **Hybrid Swordmage:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Swordmage Warding, a +1 untyped bonus to AC when wielding a light or heavy blade, or +3 if your offhand is free.
- **Hybrid Wizard:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Arcane Implement Mastery. Select Staff of Defense to get a +1 untyped bonus to AC while wielding a staff, or a +Con untyped bonus to the defense targeted by a triggering attack 1/encounter as an interrupt. (For an attack against AC, this replaces the basic +1 bonus, since untyped bonuses from the same class feature do not stack.)

### And, technically

- **Hybrid Cleric:** If your DM allows the battle cleric features from *Dragon 400*, you can select Battle Cleric's Lore in place of Healer's Lore as a base feature to gain a +2 shield bonus to AC.
- **Hybrid Fighter:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get a Fighter Combat Talent. Tempest Style (from *Martial Power*) gives you the feat Two-Weapon Defense for a +1 untyped bonus to AC and Reflex when you wield a weapon in each hand. Brawler Style (from *Martial Power 2*) gives you a +1 untyped bonus to AC and a +2 untyped bonus to Fortitude when your off-hand is free. If your DM allows the Arena Training feature from the *Dark Sun Campaign Setting*, it gives you a +1 untyped bonus per tier to AC when not wearing heavy armor.
- **Hybrid Ranger:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get a Ranger Fighting Style. Archer Style gives you the feat Defensive Mobility for a +2 untyped bonus to AC against all opportunity attacks, Hunter Style gives you a +4 untyped bonus to AC against opportunity attacks provoked by your ranged attack powers, and Two-Weapon Style gives you the feat Two-Weapon Defense for a +1 untyped bonus to AC and Reflex when you wield a weapon in each hand.
- **Hybrid Rogue:** You can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to get Rogue Tactics. Select Artful Dodger for a +Cha untyped bonus to AC against opportunity attacks.
- **Hybrid Vampire:** If your DM allows this playtest material from *Dragon 400*, you can spend a feat on **Hybrid Talent** to gain Vampiric Reflexes, a +2 shield bonus to AC when you are wearing light armor or no armor and not using a shield.